# Get webpack-dev-server instance port inside webpack config

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-2

How can I get the port number of the webpack-dev-server instance inside my webpack.config.js file when running webpack-dev-server from the command line/NPM script? I can't just use the port number defined in the `devServer` object because the server will increment that number if there is a port collision (from serving another project at the same time). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't quite get to what I originally wanted: specifically it is not calling webpack-dev-server from the command line and it is not making the port available in the webpack config file, but for my purposes, it is an acceptable workaround.

With [the very latest commit](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/commit/1201ac1265ef1cc7072a50a81c35bc55ea86b616) to webpack-dev-server, you can start the server with the API, request a random port by passing in `0` for the port argument and access the port number in your server.js file:

```
'use strict';

const Webpack = require('webpack');
const WebpackDevServer = require('webpack-dev-server');
const webpackConfig = require('./webpack.config');

const compiler = Webpack(webpackConfig);
const server = new WebpackDevServer(compiler, {
  stats: {
    colors: true
  }
});

server.listen(0, '127.0.0.1', () => {
  const port = server.listeningApp.address().port;

  // use port here
});
```

Comment: If you omit `port` in `devServer`, webpack will automatically select the next available port automatically for you. However, if you cannot omit `port` for some reason, then take a look at [portfinder-sync](https://www.npmjs.com/package/portfinder-sync) so you can use that in your webpack.config.js to set the port value. `const port = portFinderSync.getPort(8080)`

Comment: Unfortunately this no longer works with webpack-dev-server version 3+

Comment: Oh, but it turns out you can still get to it using the `onListening` option, e.g. `onListening: server => { const { port } = server.listeningApp.address(); ... }`